# Django admin - combine two models

Tags: django

I have setup a small support application at my website, but to integrate it and get the full potential out of it I as an administrator should have the opportunity to also reply onto support tickets the user has opened. Otherwise a support application is pretty useless I guess ...

So my question is how can I combine these two models at django admin to reply onto a support ticket? I need to get the replies underneath the actuall support ticket plus a form to add a reply at django admin... Can smb. Help:

```
class SupportTicketReplies(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=referential_models, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='support_ticket_reply_author', verbose_name='Author', blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Content", max_length=3000)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)


class SupportTickets(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    ticket_id = models.IntegerField(default=ticket_id_generator, unique=True, blank=False, null=False, editable=False)
    requester = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=TICKET_CATEGORY, verbose_name='Ticket Category')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    problem_description = models.TextField(max_length=3000)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_OF_TICKET, verbose_name='Ticket Status', default=0)
    reply_relation = GenericRelation(SupportTicketReplies, related_query_name='reply_relation')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using GenericRelation and not m2m field?

Comment: This allows querying and filtering from the related object... Why is this important according to this question where I want to have the ticket, the replies and the reply form on a single page at django admin?

Comment: m2m allows querying and filtering too. and you could use inlines in admin which I assume that exactly what you want. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

Comment: Thanks for that hint I will get back to this issue by tomorrow!